# Plex "Remote Access" not working with TP-Link Deco router, even with port forwarding. How do I fix this?

Tags: macos, port-forwarding, plex

Running Plex on macOS Catalina.

In the Plex "Remote Access" settings, it says it's not accessible, even though I've manually specified a port, and then configured Deco to port forward that port to the right local IP.

What gives?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://forums.plex.tv/t/relayed-connection-remote-access/281494/8) - I went to the "Antivirus" part of the Deco app, then turned off "Intrusion Prevention System". Now it works!